# How to send message to client in Socket.Stream?

Tags: c#, websocket

There is an application in C # to which I need to attach a web interface with a minimum response time (several timers are displayed), so I want to connect via socket [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server#put_together) has a great example just for me. It already shows the connection, handshake and reading a message from the client. Bonus, the JS side is shown. It just doesn't show how to compose a response to the client. The following [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#format) shows what bytes the message is from, but I still don't I can make it right.
Whenever you try to send something to the client, the connection is immediately terminated, even if you send the same byte array that came.
Please help me to make the function of sending a message, I couldn't myself ((

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You can improve your question by showing your code.  Explain where you are attempting to write to the client and what is actually happening in detail.

Comment: My code is the same as in the example. But it is worth noting that for the answer you need to anywhere in the cycle
`r = //collected array of bytes for response;
stream.Write(r, 0, r.Length);`
My problem is that I still do not understand the meaning of what is written in the documentation https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.2

Comment: I understand what code is needed, I don't understand how to create the required byte array for the response

Comment: Are you deliberately trying to work on a low level like that rather than using System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket?  Eg see https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-websocket-chat/  If you do need to work at that low level you really need to improve your question, please imagine trying to read it from an answerer's point of view.

Comment: Еhe client already has an application that runs on WPF. Adding on the web showed this little refinement and I wouldn't want to change the rest of the app too much.
Perhaps there is a way to add asp to the solution, but I need few features and I still don't know how to do it.

I was looking for ready-made libraries to work with WebSocket but they broke when I tried examples or quick start

A few evenings later, I managed to send some ascii characters. I seem to understand how it works. If everything works out, I will develop the idea tomorrow and be able to post an example of the function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it. If anyone needs it, I'll leave my code here. It is the same as on [mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server#put_together) but I added the SendEcho function

Code server on C#

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Net.Sockets;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 namespace TestSocket
 {
class Program
{
   
    public static void Main()
    {

        string ip = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 80;
        var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

        string swkaSha1Base64 = "";
        byte[] response = new byte[1];
        server.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server has started on {0}:{1}, Waiting for a connection...", ip, port);


        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        // enter to an infinite cycle to be able to handle every change in stream
        while (true)
        {
            while (!stream.DataAvailable) ;
            while (client.Available < 3) ; // match against "get"

            byte[] bytes = new byte[client.Available];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.Available);
            string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

            if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("=====Handshaking from client=====\n{0}", s);

                // 1. Obtain the value of the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" request header without any leading or trailing whitespace
                // 2. Concatenate it with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" (a special GUID specified by RFC 6455)
                // 3. Compute SHA-1 and Base64 hash of the new value
                // 4. Write the hash back as the value of "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" response header in an HTTP response
                string swk = Regex.Match(s, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
                string swka = swk + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
                byte[] swkaSha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(swka));
                swkaSha1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(swkaSha1);

                // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
                response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
                    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + swkaSha1Base64 + "\r\n\r\n");

                string x = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                Console.WriteLine(x);

                stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                bool fin = (bytes[0] & 0b10000000) != 0,
                    mask = (bytes[1] & 0b10000000) != 0; // must be true, "All messages from the client to the server have this bit set"

                if (bytes[0] == 0x88)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("соединение закрыто");
                }

                int opcode = bytes[0] & 0b00001111, // expecting 1 - text message
                    msglen = bytes[1] - 128, // & 0111 1111
                    offset = 2;

                if (msglen == 126)
                {
                    // was ToUInt16(bytes, offset) but the result is incorrect
                    msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);
                    offset = 4;
                }
                else if (msglen == 127)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TODO: msglen == 127, needs qword to store msglen");
                    // i don't really know the byte order, please edit this
                    // msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt64(new byte[] { bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[9], bytes[8], bytes[7], bytes[6] }, 0);
                    // offset = 10;
                }

                if (msglen == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("msglen == 0");
                else if (mask)
                {
                    byte[] decoded = new byte[msglen];
                    byte[] masks = new byte[4] { bytes[offset], bytes[offset + 1], bytes[offset + 2], bytes[offset + 3] };
                    offset += 4;


                    for (int i = 0; i < msglen; ++i)
                        decoded[i] = (byte)(bytes[offset + i] ^ masks[i % 4]);

                    string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
                    

                    SendEcho(stream, text); //my update
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("mask bit not set");

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
    private static void SendEcho(NetworkStream stream, string inputText)
    {
        
        byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputText);
        byte lengthHeader = 0;
        byte[] lengthCount = new byte[] { };

        if (sendBytes.Length <= 125)
            lengthHeader = (byte)sendBytes.Length;

        if (125 < sendBytes.Length && sendBytes.Length < 65535) //System.UInt16
        {
            lengthHeader = 126;

               lengthCount = new byte[] {
                (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 8),
                (byte)(sendBytes.Length)
            };
        }

        if (sendBytes.Length > 65535)//max 2_147_483_647 but .Length -> System.Int32
        { lengthHeader = 127;
            lengthCount = new byte[] {
                (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 56),
                (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 48),
                (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 40),
                (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 32),
                (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 24),
                (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 16),
                (byte)(sendBytes.Length >> 8),
                (byte)sendBytes.Length,
            };
        }
       
        List<byte> responseArray = new List<byte>() { 0b10000001 };

        responseArray.Add(lengthHeader);
        responseArray.AddRange(lengthCount);
        responseArray.AddRange(sendBytes);

        stream.Write(responseArray.ToArray(), 0, responseArray.Count);
    }

}
}
```

HTML and JS code on browser (i use chrome 98)

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
textarea { vertical-align: bottom; }
#output { overflow: auto; }
#output > p { overflow-wrap: break-word; }
#output span { color: blue; }
#output span.error { color: red; }
</style>
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
<textarea cols=60 rows=6></textarea>
<button>send</button>
<div id=output></div>
<script>
// http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

var button = document.querySelector("button"),
    output = document.querySelector("#output"),
    textarea = document.querySelector("textarea"),
    // wsUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org/",
    wsUri = "ws://127.0.0.1/",
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

button.addEventListener("click", onClickButton);

websocket.onopen = function (e) {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("WebSocket rocks");
};

websocket.onclose = function (e) {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
};

websocket.onmessage = function (e) {
    writeToScreen("<span>RESPONSE: " + e.data + "</span>");
};

websocket.onerror = function (e) {
    writeToScreen("<span class=error>ERROR:</span> " + e.data);
};

function doSend(message) {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
    websocket.send(message);
}

function writeToScreen(message) {
    output.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<p>" + message + "</p>");
}

function onClickButton() {
    var text = textarea.value;

    text && doSend(text);
    textarea.value = "";
    textarea.focus();
}
</script>
```